# Origem e diferenças de "apenas"

Tags: etimologia, diferenças, origem

A palavra *apenas*, como advérbio, no dicionário [Priberam](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/apenas), aparece com duas acepções. A primeira já me era comum, mas a segunda raramente a encontro.

Como a palavra *apenas* foi formada? Ela teve o seu uso, primeiramente, com o mesmo significado de *somente*?

Numa avaliação inicial, surgiu-me a ideia de associar *apenas*, com o sentido de *custosamente*, a "a penas". Por exemplo:

- Ele conseguiu aquilo, custosamente.
- Ele conseguiu aquilo, apenas.
- Ele conseguiu aquilo, a [duras] penas.

Teria *apenas* uma origem nesse viés? Se sim, a outra acepção (*somente)* surgira quando?

Comment: O significado 2. do Priberam parece de facto ser o mais antigo. No Corpus Informatizado do Português Medieval as duas entradas do séc XV significam _dificilmente_: «E a ssoberua que sse rregna em
tal criaçom te faz desejar sobejas rroupas & paramentos & Joyas . tanto
que a penas pẽssas em outra cousa». O que é estranho é haver tão poucas entradas (talvez houvesse outra variante que não _apenas_ / _a penas_?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[***Apenas*** tem no Priberam três significados:](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/apenas)

> *Advérbio:* **1** somente; **2** com custo, dificilmente, escassamente.
>
> *Conjunção:* **3** assim que, logo que

Os significados **2** e **3** parecem ser os mais antigos e podem quase sempre ser expressos no português moderno por ***quase não, mal:***

> [significado 2] E ho vento lançava muita area em cima deles, assi que eram cubertos que ***apenas*** se podiam levantar. (*Vida e Feitos de Júlio César*, 1400-1500.)
>
> [significado 2] E o poboo, correndo comtra aquelle fraire, lamçoulhe pedras porllo matar, empero foy livrado por os mais poderossos do arroido do poboo e ***apenas*** escapou de seer apedrado. [(*Crónicas dos Frades Menores 1209-85*, manuscrito do século XV)](https://archive.org/stream/crnicadaordemd02nune#page/18/mode/2up/search/apenas)
>
> [significado 3] Antes creeria eu aquella arvor pasarse ella meesma a esta parte do rio que nom creer que Deus tamto me leixasse em aquestes males, see com a sua dulçedom elle amasse a mim tanto como eu amo a elle. Çertamemte esto he maravilha que, ***apenas*** ella avia acabado de dizer estas palavras, ex que arvor supitamemte foy arramcada de rraizees e trespasada donde estava aa outra parte do riio. [(Idem.)](https://archive.org/stream/crnicadaordemd02nune#page/18/mode/2up/search/apenas)

Com os significados **2** e **3** usou-se também no passado, ainda que com menor frequência, a variante ***a penas:***

> A esta [cobra] chamão pella lingoa dos jndios Giboyassii. Outras ha muito maiores e mais pessonhentas doutra casta differete. Saõ taõ grandes entanto extremo que ***a penas*** desaseis indios podião leuar hûa que matarão junto da costa antre os portugeses, a esta cobra chamão Surucucu (Pêro de Magalhães de Gândavo, *Tractado da prouinçia do Brasil*, 1570?)

Andei a ver no [Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/), e ***apenas/a penas*** com os significados **2** e **3** ocorre a partir do século XV (20 ocorrências no século XV, 71 no XVI; o Corpus tem pouco material dos séculos anteriores). O significado **1**, ***somente***, só aparece no século XVII, mas com baixa frequência, que mantém no XVIII. No século XIX este significado torna-se muito frequente, enquanto o **2** só rara e dubiamente se encontra; o **3** ainda é frequente nas obras de Eça de Queiroz e Machado de Assis, no limiar do século XX.

Dando crédito à hipótese do surgimento tardio do significado **1** temos um dicionário de português-latim de 1697, em que ***a penas*** é traduzido para latim como ***vix*** (ênfase minha):

> ***Apenar***, id est, ***por pena*** || Facere censionem. Multam irrogare. ***A penas***|| ***Vix***. (Bento Pereira, *Tesouro da Lingua Portuguesa 1*, 1697.)
>
> ***Vix***, Adv. || ***A penas***, escassamento, com trabalho, & difficuldade; item nam. < Vix dum. || A penas, &c. Cic. (Bento Pereira, *Prosodia 7*, 1697.)

De acordo com o [Wictionary, o latim ***vix***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vix) corresponde exatamente aos significados **2** e **3**. O autor parece portanto não conhecer ou reconhecer o significado **1**, apesar de já se encontrarem à época alguns *apenas* com esse significado.

O [Aulete digital indica que *apenas*](http://www.aulete.com.br/Apenas) tem origem em ***a penas***, em que [*pena* (2)](http://www.aulete.com.br/pena) tem aqui o significado de *castigo*. O mesmo indica o [Dicionário da Academia Real Espanhola](http://dle.rae.es/?id=38BNs6H), mas em castelhano, [*pena*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SQbVLbD) também significa *dolor, tormento o sentimiento corporal* e *dificuldad, trabajo*. Estes significados explicariam razoavelmente *apenas* no sentido **2**, pelos menos nalguns contextos. Não me parece impossível que *pena* tivesse tido estes significados também no português antigo (encontrei muito escassa evidência disso no Corpus). Ou simplesmente que *apenas* tenha sido importado do castelhano. É curioso que no [castelhano *apenas*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=38BNs6H) tem apenas os significados **2** e **3**, e que ainda ocorre a forma *a penas*.

Comment: _a penas_ tb ocorre no português antigo. A Gramática Histórica de Said Ali indica ainda a forma _a grandes penas_.

Comment: É  verdade. Eu não tinha encontrado nos séc. XIV e XV, e e nem procurei no outros. Mas há algumas nos séc. XVI, XVII e XVIII. O Corpus não tem a grandes penas

Comment: O Aulete lista _a duras penas_, que parece ter o mesmo significado (_dificilmente_).

Comment: @Artefacto Também não encontro *a duras penas*

Comment: @Artefacto Para acabar com as tosse procurei *a * penas*. Há uma porção de *a maas penas/a más penas* com o mesmo significado, mas todas no *Livro da Montaria* de D. joão I.

Comment: O que não me é completamente ainda claro é como passamos de um valor aproximante (_isto, mas por pouco_, aproximando-se por baixo, quase não lá chegamos) para um valor de exclusão (_isto, mas não mais_). Este salto não se deu no espanhol. Talvez via frases como _Hemos llegado apenas hace una semana_ em que  as duas interpretações são semelhantes.

Comment: @Artefacto Encontrei vária passagens com significado ambíguo, desse tipo *apenas hace uma semana*. Um via que me parece possível é o exagero: dizer-se *ele apenas (mal) cá esteve uma hora* quando na verdade ele esteve uma hora e cinco minutos; e isto ser de tal forma abusado, que *apenas* passa a ser equivalente a *somente*. Do mesmo modo que hoje se corre o risco de *literalmente* vir a significar *figuradamente*.