# Qual é a origem de "valer a pena"?

Tags: origem-histórica, expressões-idiomáticas

Em **valer a pena**, no [sentido](https://dicionario.priberam.org/valer%20a%20pena) de algo

> Merecer o esforço, o trabalho. = COMPENSAR

sempre entendi que a "pena" era o "custo" desse algo. Mas existe alguma evidência desse ser mesmo o sentido?

Pergunto porque tenho visto afirmações contrárias, de que a origem seria, por exemplo, a mitologia egípcia (e.g., [aqui](https://roldanalencar.blogspot.com/2017/06/como-surgiu-expressao-vale-pena.html) e [aqui](https://valeuapenasaber.wordpress.com/2015/03/20/expressao-vale-a-pena/)), em que o destino final da pessoa depende do seu coração pesar menos que uma *pena* de um pavão ou avestruz. Outra origem aventada é de seria uma referência a valer o uso da pena para escrever uma carta.

Essas histórias alternativas me parecem obviamente improváveis mas, sem evidência em contrário, depende-se do bom senso e a discussão se torna subjetiva, por isso a pergunta.

Comment: não sei quem se lembra de tretas dessas, especialmente com uma expressão relativamente transparente. E basta ver que espanhol tem também _merecer/valer la pena_ e que _pena_ nesse significado é _pluma_ em espanhol, para perceber que _pena_ aí não se refere a aves

Comment: @Artefacto Excelente ponto o do espanhol. Na pergunta tirei o "histórica" de "evidência *histórica*", porque qualquer evidência é bem-vinda - e tua observação já seria uma boa resposta.

Comment: @Artefacto, então isso foi um português que foi nas cruzadas. No regresso passou pelo Egito, visitou as pirâmides, e como não falava bem a língua, não compreendeu bem o guia turístico, fez uma confusão com pesagem do coração contra a pena e criou a expressão *valer a pena*. Depois um espanhol veio a Portugal, não percebeu que *pena* neste contexto era pena de ave, e levou a expressão para Espanha alterando o significado de pena. Então não se tá mesmo a ver?

Comment: @Artefacto, não é que eu dê um pintelho pelas explicações avícolas, mas parece que *pena* já foi usado como ’pluma’ em espanhol (vê [RAE](https://dle.rae.es/?id=SQbVLbD|SQczESN), *pena* 2).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***Pena*** — não a das aves, que vem do latim *penna* — mas a outra que vem do latim *poena* (’punição, sofrimento’), atualmente significa basicamente ’desgosto, dó’ ou ’punição judicial’, mas no passado, segundo o [dicionário Moraes Silva de 1789](https://books.google.pt/books?id=kPBDAQAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA180&lpg=RA1-PA180&dq=%22pena%20f%20f%20mal%20fizico%20ou%20moral%22&source=bl&ots=Ev-As6qr5H&sig=ACfU3U2aV-XsyxpMH1yrSosEw9CpruWB_A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjUmZqStuzkAhUK1BoKHVq5AXIQ6AEwAHoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22pena%20f%20f%20mal%20fizico%20ou%20moral%22&f=false) significou também ’trabalho’ e ’incómodo’; e por *trabalho* entendia-se também, segundo [o mesmo dicionário](https://books.google.pt/books?id=KvFj2p9f8RgC&pg=RA1-PA478&lpg=RA1-PA478&dq=%22difficuldade%20e%20incommodo%22&source=bl&ots=-2_nt0ecLd&sig=ACfU3U1Q096Y4s7tDjcpOdBkqfE4cjbG7A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiGjIGPtOzkAhXyA2MBHTfIBHAQ6AEwBXoECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22difficuldade%20e%20incommodo%22&f=false), “[a] difficuldade, e incommodo do trabalhar” e “[c]oisa que incommoda, afflige o corpo, ou espirito.” [A edição de 1823](https://books.google.pt/books?id=lwxaAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA442&lpg=PA442&dq=%22com%20pena%20punha%20os%20p%C3%A9s%20no%20ch%C3%A3o%22&source=bl&ots=RgvhFQyKDB&sig=ACfU3U1ZBZsAZ26w_NESGH5s-BG3dRPqkA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwii4fTs1ezkAhUtD2MBHcICCd0Q6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22com%20pena%20punha%20os%20p%C3%A9s%20no%20ch%C3%A3o%22&f=false) complementa com exemplos de autores clássicos (negrito meu; grafia original em todas as citações):

> **PENA**, s. fem. **Dor, molestia** : “com *pena* punha os pés no chão” […] **§ Dôr. § Afflicção. § Trabalho.** […] “*a mim me custará pouca, ou nenhuma* pena *a sua averiguação*”  […] **§ Trabalho, incommodo**: “*recebia o mercador muita* pena *em acordá-lo o Mouro com os brados*” […] “carne, vinho… tudo com *pena* se achava” (com trabalho, em tempo de fome, que houve)

Estes significados de *pena* refletem-se ainda hoje no adjetivo [*penoso* (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/penoso). Precisamente, em [1827, Francisco de São Luís (*Glossario das palavras da lingua franceza…*, p. 103)](https://archive.org/stream/glossariodaspal00luizgoog#page/n113/mode/2up), ao desaconselhar *penível* por galicismo, diz que o que se deve usar é “penoso, molesto, incommodo, trabalhoso” ou “que causa pena”.

Eu encontrei a locução *valer a pena* só a partir de 1787, e para mim não restam dúvidas que por esta altura o *pena* da locução seria entendido como ’trabalho, incómodo’.  E foi esse o entendimento unânime dos lexicógrafos: a locução aparece em todos os dicionários que vi no verbete *pena* de *poena* e não no *pena* de ave. Ver [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/pena), [Michaelis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/palavra/okqeo/pena-2/), [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/pena), [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/pena). O dicionário de Domingos Vieira, de 1874, o primeiro onde encontrei a locução diz precisamente “*[m]erecer* ou *valer alguma cousa a pena*; o trabalho que se emprega”. Tem também as locuções *com duas penas* e *com duras penas*, que define como “com grande difficuldade ou trabalho”. Também o nosso *apenas*, muito antes de significar ’somente’, significou ’com grande dificuldade’ (ver [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1840/origem-e-diferen%C3%A7as-de-apenas)).

Fica aqui a título de curiosidade o exemplo de 1787, o mais antigo que encontrei:

> E valia a penna de provar a divindade do Envagelho com tanto enfase para o contradizer depois sem lhe fazer quartel?
> [Bergier e José da Costa Torres (tradutor), *O Deismo*, Lisboa, 1787, p. 201.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=wslCAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA201&dq=%22valia%20a%20penna%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj80OnuqubkAhVk5eAKHcnNCgQQ6AEIezAK#v=onepage&q=%22valia%20a%20penna%22&f=false)

Existe também *valoir la peine* no francês e *merecer* ou *valer la pena* no espanhol. Com a diferença que [*peine*](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/peine/59016?q=peine#58655) ainda significa ’esforço que custa’, e o [espanhol *pena*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=SQbVLbD%7CSQczESN), ’dificuldade, trabalho’.

*Peine* e o espanhol *pena* não significam pena de ave em geral. No entanto isto não é o argumento decisivo que gostaríamos, se ainda precisássemos dele, pois o espanhol [*pena*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=SQbVLbD%7CSQczESN) (mais abaixo na mesma página) já significou ’pena de ave’, e ainda significa ’pena de escrever’ e ’penas longas usadas no voo’. E *peine* tem um homófono [*penne*](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/penne/59249?q=penne#58887), que é as tais penas longas.

### Origens alternativas

Não sei se a evidência que apresentei convence a todos. Mas nesta altura do campeonato eu inverto a pergunta: os proponentes de hipóteses alternativas que mostrem a sua plausibilidade. Como é que se passou de uma crença no antigo Egito para uma locução ibérica e francesa. Na verdade isto é irrelevante. Mesmo que o primeiríssimo uso desta combinação de palavras fosse um mestre-escola que dissesse ao discípulo, “a tua redação não vale (o desgaste d’) a pena”, quem a usasse noutro contexto reinterpretaria imediatamente *pena* como ’trabalho, incómodo’.

Mas o pessoal gosta de inventar origens exóticas. Também há a tese que *valer a pena* significou inicialmente ’justificar (uma pessoa arriscar) a pele’, pois *pena* já significou ’pele’ ou ’couro’ (ver [nesta cantiga medieval](https://cantigas.fcsh.unl.pt/cantiga.asp?cdcant=466&pv=sim); clicar nos ícones à esquerda para ver os significados). Ok, esta fui eu que inventei. Mas já alguém sugeriu (ver [artigo no Ciberdúvidas)](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-origem-da-expressao-valer-a-pena/26798) que a locução nasceu quando Richard Strauss visitou Sintra e disse “[c]onheço a Itália, a Sicília, a Grécia e o Egipto e nunca vi nada que valha [**a** Pena](https://www.mundoportugues.pt/lugares-de-sonho-em-portugal-palacio-da-pena-em-sintra/)

Comment: Mais uma resposta magistral baseada em pesquisa exemplar. Obrigado.

Comment: @stafusa, obrigado. Reparaste que a sintaxe no exemplo de 1787 é um nadinha diferente da atual, *não valer a pena **de**?* Encontrei outras assim no sXIX.

Comment: Sim, bem condizente com o sentido de "trabalho", "incômodo".

Comment: Não encontraste _merecer a pena_ antes de 1787? E o espanhol ainda usa a preposição [nalgumas circunstâncias](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=pena).

Comment: @Artefacto, não, só encontrei a partir de 1820 e picos, quando *não valer a pena* se torna muito comum. Em espanhol há já em 1540, e em francês em 1587. O Houaiss diz que alguns puristas condenaram *valer a pena* como galicismo, e que se deveria era usar *merecer o esforço* ou *adiantar* (não sugerem *merecer a pena*), portando talvez seja mesmo tardio; por outro lado não faltaram puristas a condenar construções antigas como estrangeirismos.